# Bitmap drawing too slow - is openGL the solution?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am writing a live wallpaper for Android. The wallpaper includes a bit of bitmap processing, and it's too slow for me. It's running on a Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300), so the display size is 720x1280. When the wallpaper service is running, the device slows down and the launcher slows down too. How can i achieve a smooth wallpaper, should i use OpenGL? I searched other forums etc., and some users say that OpenGL isn't really faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users don't know the difference between bitmap and OpenGL, developers do! And yes, you have to use OpenGL for a smooth wallpaper.